# Javascript - Can't freeze and seal things

Tags: javascript, object

Why can't I seal and Freeze o.id, o.id.name, o.id.surname respectively?.

```
var o = Object.defineProperty({}, "id", 
          {value: {name:{value:"Eduardo",writable:true,enumerable:true,configurable:true},
               surname:{value:"Valente", writable:true,enumerable:true,configurable:true}},
              writable:true,enumerable:true,configurable:true});
      Object.preventExtensions(o.id);
      console.assert(Object.isExtensible(o.id), "o.id is not extensible");
      Object.seal(o.id);
      console.assert(Object.isSealed(o.id), "o is not sealed");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "id")));
      Object.freeze(o.id.name);
      Object.freeze(o.id.surname);
      console.assert(Object.isFrozen(o.id.name), "o.id.name is not frozen");
      console.assert(Object.isFrozen(o.id.surname), "o.id.surname is not frozen");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "id")));

      function display(o)
      {
         o["id"]["name"] = "Felipe";
         o["id"]["surname"] = "Badia";
         console.log(o["id"]["name"]);
         console.log(o["id"]["surname"]);
      }    

      display(o);
```

Comment: Instead of actively trying to circumvent our policies, why don't you tell us what the problem is?

Comment: You seem to mistaken think that `freeze()` affects properties rather than objects.

Comment: I didn't want to circumvent the policies, I just wanted to post my question. But there was a problem with "text too short".

Comment: Yes; the text **is** too short.  You should tell us what the problem is, and what happens.

Comment: I already told ya. I can't freeze or seal the mentioned properties. I hadn't anything more to say.

Comment: @SLaks - rephrasing SLaks' comment: PhoenixWings please add WHAT you trying to achieve. It could be that you are asking the wrong question. i.e. are you trying to make o and all of its properties immutable? or something else? What happens if 1 of o's properties is share with another object?

Answer (score 0):

You're sealing the property-descriptor-like objects which are the initial values of the `o.id` and `o.value` properties.

That doesn't prevent you from re-assigning those properties to point to other values.

Frozen objects have nothing to do with the writability of any properties that may contain them.

Comment: @SLaksFrozen objects have nothing to do with read-only properties.from Javascript the Definitive Guide: "Object.freeze() locks objects down even more tightly. In addition to making the object
nonextensible and its properties nonconfigurable, it also makes all of the object’s own
data properties read-only." What can be frozen or sealed then?

Comment: @PhoenixWings: I mean they have nothing to do with properties that contain them.  I'll clarify.